# Как вставить текст в input по нажатию на элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Например, у меня есть форма, в ней `input`, сверху кнопка, мне надо чтоб по нажатию на кнопку определённый текст вставлялся в `input`.

Я сделал такое, но не так как надо: у меня текст добавляется в конец, а мне надо чтоб текст добавлялся туда, где находится каретка

Comment: "туда где курсор" это куда?

Comment: покажите ваш код, который не правильно работает

Comment: А такая кнопка одна или их будет много?

Comment: Кнопок много....

Comment: "где Курсор" это например я ввёл в инпут "привет", потом нажал мышью между "при" и "вет", и и там появился значок (cursor:text;), я нажимаю на кнопку после это-го и текст вставляется, но вставляется после слова "привет", а мне надо чтоб там где cursor:text; тоесть между "при" и "вет"

Comment: Не отвечайте комментариями, а отредактируйте Ваш вопрос дополнив его уточняющей информацией, чтоб отвечающим не приходилось гадать, какая конкретно у Вас проблема. Через несколько комментариев они будут свёрнуты...

Comment: Я просто незнаю как ещё объяснить

Comment: Приведите здесь код с комментариями (`Ctrl + M` в редакторе) и он может сказать больше. И дело даже не в Вас, а в тех кто в последствии столкнётся с похожей задачей/проблемой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверное речь про определение позиции курсора, это можно сделать как-то так:

```js
function insert (word) {
  let inp = document.querySelector('input');
  let start = inp.selectionStart;
  inp.value = inp.value.substring(0, start) + word +
    inp.value.substring(inp.selectionEnd, inp.value.length) 
    inp.focus();
    inp.setSelectionRange(start, start + word.length)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="insert(' hello ')">insert hello</button>
<button onclick="insert(' aloha ')">insert aloha</button>
<input value='test'>
```

Comment: Кстати, вы случайно не знаете, как после клика на такую кнопку, потом поставить фокус ровно туда, где добавился текст? (достаточно ссылки, где искать)

Comment: Да спасибо, помогло, я просто незнал как сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME дополнил ответ